# how to plot a muti level variable in muti graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make plots with every 3 colors in one graph. for my sample data, I will need two graphs. Also, is it possible to just plot top 3 colors group with most obs? What should I do. Currently I have 6 in one graph. This is just a sample data, my real data has about 50 levels, and my codes won't be able to create sth that is readable. Too crawdad.

[image]

The codes are:

```
ID<- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18")
Group<-c("A","B","C","D","D","D","A","B","D","C","B","D","A","A","C","B","B","B")
Color<-c("Green","Blue","Red","Red","Black","Yellow","Green","Green","Yellow","Purple","Red","Yellow","Yellow","Yellow","Green","Red","Red","Green")
Realy_Love<-c("Y","N","Y","Y","N","N","Y","Y","Y","N","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y","N","Y")
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Group, Color, Realy_Love)

Sample<-Sample.data %>%
    count(Group, Color, sort = TRUE)

Sample<-Sample.data %>%
    count(Group, Color, Realy_Love, sort = TRUE)
    
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Sample.data %>%
  count(Group, Color, sort = TRUE) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = n, fill = Color)) + 
         geom_col() + 
         facet_wrap(~ Color)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, make two graphs with 3 colors each, you need to create a variable that groups the colors that will go into each group. We will use the `case_when()` function for this

```
Sample.data %>%
  count(Group, Color, sort = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Facet = case_when(Color %in% c("Black", "Blue", "Green") ~ "Group 1",
                           Color %in% c("Purple", "Red", "Yellow") ~ "Group 2")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = n, fill = Color)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Facet)
```

[image: Graph 1]

For your second request, about plotting only the 3 colors with most observations, we can use the `fct_lump()` function from the `forcats` package:

```
Sample.data %>%
  mutate(Color = fct_lump(f = Color, 
                          n = 3,
                          other_level = "Other colors")) %>%
  filter(Color != "Other colors") %>%
  count(Group, Color, sort = TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = n, fill = Color)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Question 1 in fact wants two graphs that looks like you made for question 2. I want to have two graphs that bars, each have 3 small plots for a color. Is it a way without manually select which 3 color are selected in the graph 1 and 2?

Comment: Sorry but I’m not understanding what variables you want to use for each detail of the plot. You want 2 graphs, but what will be the variable or criteria that divides your data in two? I need to know that to help you. The you say you want 3 small plots for a color, what does that mean? A graph for every group? (ABCD...)